# How to access redis server via domain name?

Tags: nginx, redis, proxy

I'm trying to make my redis server accessible via domain name, to instead of writing "ip:port" I would simply use "redis.example.org" in my applications. (remote applications)

I tried to achieve this using nginx and Redis2 module but I could not make it work, is nginx even the technology to use this for?

The thing is, I don't even know what terms to search to find my answer, what is this kind of "proxy" to a redis server called? (in future I want to use domain to access my postgres server as well, so a general solution would be great)

Thanks.

Comment: The term you're looking for is `dns`. A redis server is just like any other server in this regard, if you want to reach it with via using a domain name, instead of a ip address, you need a dns server to do that for you. Pretty much like you do for a website that is served by a http server.

Comment: @nitrin0 Thank you so much, can you please point me to the right documents, tutorials for this? that would be extremely kind of you

Comment: Where do you have your redis server hosted? That company/service provider would be the best place to start, i'm sure they can help you. Configuring dns for a redis server it's the exact same thing as configuring dns for a website (basically it's just a mapping between a name/uri and a ip address). In any case, [this](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/dns-guide-beginners/) is a good introduction to this subject.